# How can I generate this code in Racket/Scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to generate code in the following way:

```
(define (foo str)
  (map (lambda (x) (* 100 x)) (hash-ref dd str)))

(define sth `(begin 
               (define dd (make-hash (list (cons "L" (list 1 2 3)))))
               (hash-set! dd "H" ,(foo "L"))
               dd))
```

(I will write `sth` to a `sth.rkt` file and execute it)

However, this doesn't work, because in the code for `foo`, it references on the `dd` identifier that is in the generated code, and therefore does not exist yet!

There is a way that I can generate code like this:

```
(define sth `(begin 
                (define dd (make-hash (list (cons "L" (list 1 2 3)))))
                (hash-set! dd "H" (foo "L"))))
```

and prepend the function `foo`, but I don't really want that `foo` in my final file!
How can I work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you're doing work that really requires code generation?  Nothing in the example you've shown us requires it yet, as you can do something like this.  In Racket:

```
#lang racket

;; When this file is required, dd will be provided to the outside.
(provide dd)

(define (foo str)
  (map (lambda (x) (* 100 x)) (hash-ref dd str)))

(define dd (make-hash (list (cons "L" (list 1 2 3)))))
(hash-set! dd "H" (foo "L"))
```

This is a *module* that can be used by other programs.  A module in Racket hides everything except for the items that are **provided**.

If you can explain why you want to do a code generation approach, maybe that will help us understand the question better.  For code generation, a macro approach will probably work better than generating an s-expression and writing it to a file.  See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/macros.html for example.

Comment: Yes, I am writing an interpreter, and I need to transform code, and generate new code in S-expression to execute, for every transforming passes (that's why I write the s-expression to file to execute). Part of it I take macro approach but not this one nor the `provide`, but thanks for your answer.

Comment: At the risk of giving you more grief, it's still not clear (to me, anyway) that you need to write things out to a file.  I understand that you're writing an interpreter, and that you need to take user code and manipulate it.  However, there's no reason why you can't go from manipulating it directly to evaluating it, is there?  I think more details are probably needed here....

Comment: @JohnClements I transform language say A to s-expression, and I want to make sure the transformation is semantic equivalent, the way I do this (maybe sound stupid:) is writing the transformed code to a file, execute it and compare the result with the result from executing language A. I think at the end, I will pipeline results from each phrases in code, rather than in file.

Comment: Why not evaluate it *without* writing it to a file? The idea behind Racket Modules is to give you the kind of isolation/control over evaluation that you could get through writing it to a file.

Comment: I think your saying makes great sense. Sorry for the ignorance before. I will definitely adapt to use Racket modules soon.